# How to select next element with unique id on each anchor click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an active class on first element and I want when I click on the anchor to add active class to next element, get the id and class of the element with active class with javascript.

I want to do this by using $(this). How would I do that?

```html
  <p class="question active" id="q_1">
    Question 1?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_2">
    Question 2?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_3">
    Question 3?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_4">
    Question 4?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_5">
    Question 5?
  </p>

  <a class="button" href=""></a>
```

I've used the next jquery code but I don't like that:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active').hide().next().show().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Your code is weird. You use `active` in your html but your javascript is using `selected`

Comment: now do you use active or selected as your marker class?

Comment: Sorry, modified that.

Comment: downvote: question is unclear

Comment: I think my question is more than clear. There are people that are jumping to conclusions like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` will not always works. For example, when the active element will be the last (so `q_5` in your example), `next` will return an empty jQuery collection.

And if you can, it is better to avoid `show` and `hide` in jQuery. Use your `active` class to do that.

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var $next = $('p.active').removeClass('active').next('p.question');

    if (!$next.length) {
        $next = $('#q_1');
    }

    $next.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
p:not(.active) {
    display : none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question active" id="q_1">
    Question 1?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_2">
    Question 2?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_3">
    Question 3?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_4">
    Question 4?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_5">
    Question 5?
  </p>

  <a class="button" href="">Change</a>
```

Comment: I don't want to use next(), show(), hide(). I prefer to use pure javascript with add and removeClass. By getting and selecting id of active element on click. Because if I have multiple divs that won't work.

Comment: If you want the id of the active element you can just do $('p.active').attr('id'); But i'm not really sure of what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $('.active').removeClass('active').next();
    if(a.hasClass('question')){
        a.addClass('active');
    }else{
    $("#q_1").addClass('active');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to use next(), show(), hide(). I prefer to use pure javascript with add and removeClass. By getting and selecting id of active element on click. Because if I have multiple divs that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

similar to already added answers but here we code (not tested):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    if ($('p.question').length > 0) {
        $('p.question').each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                var thisIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/));
                if (thisIndex < $('p.question').length) {
                    $('#q_' + (thisIndex + 1)).addClass('active');
                }
                else  $('#q_1').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

***********************EDIT*********************

```
$(this).click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh, man...You are the only one who understood me. This kind of thing I meant when I asked my question. I'll test it and try to understand and come back with vote and accepted answer if it's ok. Thanks

Comment: no probs, may need a slight bit of tweaking but concept is what you hopefully need.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What I want is like when I click on a div or a link to add a class to that div. Like a menu where I need to have an active element when I click on it. I my case I want the same thing but adapted to my code.

Comment: @Ionut oh right, that's simple... will add to asnwer

Comment: But I want on button click.

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind the anchor tag and add/remove active class

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('p.active').removeClass('active').next('p.question').addClass('active')
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/feud0n1q/)

---

**Edit**

Based on comment - to do this with pure js (no jQuery) we can use the following code

```
<p class="question active" id="q_1">
    Question 1?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_2">
    Question 2?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_3">
    Question 3?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_4">
    Question 4?
  </p>
  <p class="question " id="q_5">
    Question 5?
  </p>

  <a class="button" href="#" onClick='return SelectNextQ()'>Click me</a>


function SelectNextQ(){
    var allQs = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
    var bFound = false;
    for(var i=0; i<allQs.length; i++){
        if(bFound){
            allQs[i].className = allQs[i].className + ' active';
            return false; // break from loop
        }
        if(allQs[i].className.indexOf('active') > -1){
            bFound = true;
            allQs[i].className = 'question';
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/feud0n1q/1/)

Comment: @Magus. What should happen after last statement is not clear from the question

Comment: @lonut. What do you mean by this sort of code. Do you mean to say that you don't want to use jQuery?

Comment: Yes. kinda'. I don't want to use next(), show(), hide(). I prefer to use pure javascript with add and removeClass. By getting and selecting id of active element on click.

Comment: @lonut. I've edited my answer and added the code for doing the same using pure javascript...